# woocomerce slider show only 2 images after all that and hidden all of them images

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying and finding out a solution in woocommerce i want to show only woocommerce slider two images after that all of them images is hidden beacause i made a custom checkbox i will checked on custom checkout 3 slider image would be.

not solution i found in woocommerce product gallery slider

this my checkbox custom code

```
function custom_label_printing() {
        global $product;

        woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_label_printing_checkbox', array( 
            'type' => 'checkbox', 
            'class' => array('custom-label-checkbox'), 
            'label' => __('Want to be custom label?'), 
            'required' => false,
        ), '' ); 

        // woocommerce_form_field('custom_label_printing', array(
        //     'type'     => 'text',
        //     'class'    => array('custom-label-printing-field form-row-wide'),
        //     'label'    => __('Custom Label', 'woocommerce'),
        //     'required' => false, // or false
        // ),'');
        
        ?>
        <div class="form-row custom-label">
            <div class="personalize-label">
                <label for="field-personalize-label1" class="form-label">For:</label>
                <div class="form-controls">
                    <input type="text" class="field custom-label-printing-field form-row-wide" name="custom_label_printing" id="field-personalize-label" value="" placeholder="Personalize here..." maxlength="23">
                </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
                <span class="input-count" data-maxlength="23">23</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="product-title" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" id="product-title">
            </div>
        </div> 
    <?php }
```

Comment: Sorry, not able to understand the connection between the checkbox and slider. And Which slider you're talking about? can you please provide more detailed information?

Comment: hi, i am talking about the left side of slider on woocommerce product slider. i am adding a simple custom check before add to cart button. i want when i click on custom checkbox image will be add into woocomerce slider

Comment: Ok, I understand the requirement now, This can be done but I have never done such kind of customization. However if you can code then I will give you an idea how you can do it. You can have your checkbox thing and map checkboxes values with image url in your JS file hardcoded or you can use `data-attr` then you can add  `onChange` event on checkbox clicks and get the selected images. Then you'll have to get/create the `flexbox` JS object for products gallery slider & destory the existing gallery slider then add the images in HTML with some validation and `init` the `flexbox` on gallery again.